# When is the quotient of a geodesic space again a geodesic space?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry, quotient-space

I asked this on the math.stackexchange forum about a week ago but did not get any answers so I figured I might try it here as well. This is a straight up copy paste from my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3431802/when-is-the-quotient-of-a-geodesic-space-again-a-geodesic-space).

I am interested in the behavior of the quotient semi-metric on geodesic spaces, i.e. length spaces where there is always a minimal curve between two points.

I used the following definition of the quotient semi-metric: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $R$ an equivalence relation on $X$. The quotient semi-metric $d_R$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
d_R([x],[y]):=\inf  \{\sum_{i=1}^n d(x_i,y_i) \mid  x R x_1, \ y R y_n, \ x_{i+1} R y_i \ \forall i=1, \ldots n-1, n \in \mathbb{N} \} 
\end{equation}

This construction in general yields a semi-metric space $(X/R,d_R)$. One can then identify points of vanishing $d_R$-distance in $X/R$ to obtain a metric space which I will denote by $X/d_R$.

In several sources (e.g. Burago, Burago, Ivanov - A course in metric geometry or Bridson, Haeflinger - Metric spaces of non-positive curvature) there is a result that states:

If $(X,d)$ is a length space, then $X/d_R$ is also a length space. In other words if I start with a length space and then identify points of zero distance in the quotient semi-metric I end up with a length space again.

My intuition is that if I start with a geodesic space then the resulting length space need not be a geodesic space. My question then is if there are certain assumptions I can impose on my geodesic space (or on the equivalence relation?) such that after this construction I obtain again a geodesic space? I am grateful not only for answers but also for references! Also a nice/intuitive counterexample would be appreciated!

Comment: Indeed, a the resulting length space need not be a geodesic (if you will ask, I will give an example). For your main question --- try to explain how you plan to appply it, otherwise you might get a useless answer.

Comment: Yes, I would very much like an example please! I do not have a specific application in mind. I came across this statement while writing my Master's thesis and wondered about the geodesic case.

Comment: Let $X$ be the unit sphere in the Hilbert space. Note that poles of $X$ can be connected by an infinite collection of geodesics such with midpoints $m_1,m_2,\dots$ lying on distance at least $1$ from each other. Glue together the $(1-1/10^n)/10$-neightborhood of $m_n$ --- the obtained space is not geodesic.